# Inherit from subclass error

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a book and following the examples shown. I'm stuck here. It's a copy of the example in the book.

How come this doesn't work- I think the problem lies at "Change klass's prototype".

The error i'm getting is 'breath is not a function'

Can someone explain me how and why? Many thanks.

```
  (function() {

    var Class = function(parent){
      var klass = function(){
        this.init.apply(this, arguments);
      };

      // Change klass's prototype
      if (parent) {
        var subclass = function() { };
        subclass.prototype = parent.prototype;
        klass.prototype = new subclass;
      };

      klass.prototype.init = function(){};

      // Shortcuts
      klass.fn = klass.prototype;
      klass.fn._class = klass;
      klass._super = klass.__proto__;

      // Adding instance properties
      klass.include = function(obj) {
        var included = obj.included; // Callback
        for (var i in obj) {
            klass[i] = obj[i];
        }
        if (included) included(klass)
      };

      return klass;
    };

    var Animal = new Class;
    Animal.include({
      breath: function() {
        console.log("breath");
      }
    });

    var Cat = new Class(Animal);

    // Cat inherits from Animal
    var tommy = new Cat;
    tommy.breath();

  })();
```

Comment: Oh my, how old is this book? This kind of code is totally outdated.

Comment: Looks like they meant `klass.prototype[i] = obj[i];`

Comment: "Javascript Web Applications" By O'Reilly. I guess the book is fine to learn vanilla JS?

Comment: Cool. It worked. Here is the book. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018421.do You do not recommend it?

Comment: No, Javascript (the vanilla language itself) has changed drastically since 2011. I guess it's still fine for learning the background ideas, but it's definitely out of date technically.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot my man. I will find a more updated book :-) Just had it among my other books and felt like trying.